# Text beneath two function graphics inside of a figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes

Is there a way to put extra text under some function plots in the following code?
I need them to appear side by side on the page in the same figure and I do not what to use an extra caption. The text is supposed to be a single-lined explanation.

```
\begin{figure}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
      width=0.45\textwidth,
      ...]
         \addplot [mark=*,mark size=0.7] {(1-x)^(1/3)}
      \end{axis}
      %%%% Add some text below this function plot <-----
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \begin{tikzpicture} 
      \begin{axis}[
      width=0.45\textwidth,
      ...]
         \addplot [mark=*,mark size=0.7] {x^3-x}
      \end{axis}
      %%%% Add some text below the second function plot <-----
   \end{tikzpicture}
 \begin{end}
```

Comment: Put the tikzpictures in minipages and the text below the minipages.

Comment: Yes, but I want to have centered text under both minipage. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can (mis)use the title. Change the position of the title and use it.

```
\documentclass{Article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
      \begin{axis}[
      width=0.45\textwidth,clip=false,
      title style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},text width=0.45\textwidth,anchor=north,align=center},
      title={here comes some text below the first picture to demonstrate the dummy text.}
      ]
         \addplot [mark=*,mark size=0.7] {(1-x)^(1/3)};
      \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
      \begin{axis}[
      width=0.45\textwidth,
      title style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},text width=0.45\textwidth,anchor=north,align=center},
      title={here comes some text.}
      ]
         \addplot [mark=*,mark size=0.7] {x^3-x};
      \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess there is an easier way, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since the labels account to the width of the picture, the centered text may always seem a bit off-centered.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{showframe}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}{.35\linewidth}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
      \begin{axis}[
      width=\linewidth
      ]
         \addplot [mark=*,mark size=0.7] {(1-x)^(1/3)};
      \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}%
   \par\centering text
   \end{minipage}\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}{.55\linewidth}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
      \begin{axis}[
      width=\linewidth,
      ]
         \addplot [mark=*,mark size=0.7] {x^3-x};
      \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \par\centering text
   \end{minipage}

   \centering
   this is text, centered
   \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If you want to save some typing, you can put that in some kind of macro, though i think this time, this isn't worth it.

Are you maybe looking for subcaptions? Nice macro, called `subcaption` provided by package `subcaption`.

Comment: I see now what you'd meant, nevertheless, thank you very much for the support.

Answer (score 1):

If you assign a name to the axis, you can access the border by its anchors (north east, south west, etc.)  You can also obtain the exact dimensions of the box, which is NOT 0.45\textwidth.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newlength{\tempwidth}

\begin{document}
\fbox{% no figures in standalone class
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[name=first,width=0.45\textwidth]
         \addplot [mark=*,mark size=0.7] {(1-x)^(1/3)};
      \end{axis}
      \pgfextractx{\tempwidth}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{first}{west}}{\pgfpointanchor{first}{east}}}
      \node[below=3mm] at (first.south) 
        {\parbox{\tempwidth}{\centering Add some text below the first function}};
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \begin{tikzpicture} 
      \begin{axis}[name=second,width=0.45\textwidth]
         \addplot [mark=*,mark size=0.7] {x^3-x};
      \end{axis}
      \pgfextractx{\tempwidth}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{second}{west}}{\pgfpointanchor{second}{east}}}
      \node[below=3mm] at (second.south) 
        {\parbox{\tempwidth}{\centering Add some text below the second function}};
   \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image: text below axis]